# What is the good way to interface Ribbon control with Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, ribbon-control

I'm using Caliburn Micro for my project, and I decided to use Fluent Ribbon as part of the UI. My ShellView is really simple, and it's laid out like this:

- Ribbon Control with 4 tabs.
- ActiveItem.

The Active item is dynamically changed depending on the Ribbon's selected tab.

**Question:**

What is the proper way to use Ribbon control as a second view for my currently active ViewModel (ActiveItem), while maintaining modularity and all the goodies which come inherit with CM itself? Also, what would it take to "share" my Ribbon control among my ViewModels?

**Details:**

My ShellViewModel is of type "*Conductor.Collection.OneActive*", and it changes the ActiveItem to specific ViewModel I associate with selected tab (when event is fired).

My Ribbon is defined in XAML like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="RibbonBar" Micro:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" Micro:View.Context="Ribbon" />
```

As it shows, Ribbon control is bound to currently active item as it's context view. That actually works for one view, because due to default CMs conventions, where it looks for the contextual views in the sub namespace (e.g. if my path to the view is *Views.TasksTabView*, it will look for the Context view at *Views.TasksTab.Ribbon*).

Problem is, when I change the ActiveItem, context view can't be located anymore, due to the different namespace, so It only works for one Tab.

I've also tried writing my own ViewLocator convention but I had no success with it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelly since there are no answers, I'll answer it myself.

I did manage to write the additional ViewLocator logic to locate my Ribbon, but that created some problems (It seems that binding in CM only works once, so after Ribbon being located and bound to the VM, additional context view changes do nothing. There were some hard to find bugs as well).

I've taken a different approach then. I've separated Ribbon to it's own ViewModel, and composited it to the shell with rest of the modules. It uses EventAggregator and I also Inject it where neccessary. Not approach I was hoping for, but it works for now.

If anyone posts better answer, I'll definitelly accept that one.